# What is in the edit box is not the same as what is being shown in the browser

Tags: support, edits, markdown, code-formatting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I format my code blocks?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks)

I am trying to answer a question that I asked.  The HTML output of the code block does not match what I have type in.  How do I fix this?

https://stackoverflow.com/a/10114328/452281

Comment: What do you mean it doesn't match?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I *think* my edit fixed it.

Problem was with having tabs for indent, and using `<pre><code>` around the whole thing.

See the [editing help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) - indent code with four spaces. (Select all the code and hit the `{}` button.) Same for the data sections, just paste, select and <kbd>Ctrl-K</kbd>.

Comment: More precisely: using `<pre><code>` is fine, but needs manual HTML encoding of `<` into `&lt;`, and so on. That's not needed when using the Markdown four spaces.

Comment: Thank you.  I will look over this so it doesn't happen again.